# Option Button hook in ClearQuest

Tags: perl, radio-button, hook, clearquest

I'm trying to set a text field to display text when a group of two option buttons is set to Yes. (They are Yes and No radio buttons). I have them set so when checked, the value is 1.

When Yes is selected, text is supposed to be visible in the text field. When No is selected, I would like for the field to be blank.

Right now, when I run the test database, check Yes, and save the radio button looks like it's saving the Yes, but then reverts to having No checked.

I'm writing my hook in Perl. So far I have this in the Value Changed hook for the Yes radio button:

```
my $checked = $entity->GetFieldValue($fieldname)->GetValue();
if($checked eq "1"){
        my $setCharge = " This text when check Yes!";
        $entity->SetFieldValue("name_of_text_field", $setCharge);
}
```

the radio buttons are both SHORT_STRING as is probably evident by my string comparison.

I've tried setting the other radio button to 0 just to make sure it's not checked, but that seems redundant since only one radio button can be selected.  I've tried writing a hook for the no Value Changed, but that didn't work either.

Ideas?

Comment: It works fine if I choose Yes first. But if I choose No, save, and then realize I should have chosen Yes, it always goes back to No.

Comment: If I select Yes first, then it displays the correct text. If I select No first, then it displays the correct text. If it was set to Yes first, but you want to change it to No: No will be selected in the radio buttons, but the text is still displayed as if Yes is selected. If it was set to No first, but you want to change it to Yes: Yes will appear to be selected until you save the record at which point it will go back to selecting No. The text will display as if the No button was still selected. Is it not possible to change the value of the radio button after you have saved the record?